# Tempdata Message how to hide

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am Passing TempDatamessage to use if user login invalid login deatails i passing message "login invalid" tempdata.i just need to hide with 5 sec automatically without refresh.

```
         TempData["mesage"] = "Your User Id Is Not Activated, Please 
         Contact Our Support";
```

How to hide the message

in the view Page I am Passing

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
       function HideLabel() {
       setTimeout(function() {
        $('#msg1').fadeOut('fast');
        }, 1000); 
     </script>
     <div class="cornerpage">
        <h8 >@TempData["mesage"]</h8>
        <h8 id="msg1">@TempData["mesage1"]</h8>

       </div>
```

Comment: Can any body help me...?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call javascript after document ready.

**Example:**

```
<div class="cornerpage">       
   <h8 id='message'>@TempData["message"]</h8>
 </div>


 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
   $('#message').hide(1000);
 });
 </script>
```

please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982329/jquery-difference-between-hide-and-fadein-show-and-fadeout) like for more help.

Hopefully it's helpful for you.

Comment: <h8 >@TempData["mesage"]</h8>
   <h8 id="msg1">@TempData["mesage1"]</h8> 

correct one


   <h8 id="msg1">@TempData["mesage"]</h8>